# How to set rewrite rule to go to frontend and backend in same server with apache

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a Vue.js project and Laravel project in apache.

I put Vue.js at `C:/Apache24/htdocs/vue_project_name`, put Laravel at `C:/Apache24/htdocs/laravel_project_name`, so I can get the configuration as below:

```
Virtualhost DocumentRoot: "C:/Apache24/htdocs/".

Frontend URL: "http://domain_name/vue_project_name"

Backend URL: "http://domain_name/laravel_project_name"

Backend API URL: "http://domain_name/laravel_project_name/public/api"
```

I want to rewrite the URL when I input `http://domain_name`, browser will direct to `http://domain_name/laravel_project_name`. And I input  `http://domain_name/api`, browser will direct to `http://domain_name/laravel_project_name/public/api`.

For example, I have an API, I can call `http://domain_name/laravel_project_name/public/api/login` to get the resource but I want it simplify to `http://domain_name/api/login` to get the resource.

How to do that?

It is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs"
    ServerName domain_name
    ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I know how to do that when I input `http://domain_name`, apache will direct to `http://domain_name/laravel_project_name`, it seem like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\vue_project_name"
    ServerName domain_name
    ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\vue_project_name"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I think it will affect backend path, so I need a better solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has to be pointed to `<project_root>/public`, that is your problem...

Update the config related to laravel to be `DocumentRoot: "C:/Apache24/htdocs/laravel_project_name/public"`.

I know you are using Apache, but [see](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx) how the `Nginx` configuration points to that folder.

Comment: But if I set document root to "C:/Apache24/htdocs/laravel_project_name/public", I can not reach my vue.js project.